# Change the sound profile automatically when starting and ending charging

Tags: automation, vibration

When my phone isn't plugged into the charger, it's in my pocket, so vibration suffices for notifying me of a phone call or text message. But unlike my previous phone, it doesn't vibrate loudly enough for me to reliably hear it when it's not in my pocket. So I'd like to automatically change the sound profile to "Sound" when I plug in the phone, and "Vibrate only" when I unplug it. How can I do that?

I have experience in administering Linux PCs and servers, but I'm unfamiliar with Android internals, so I wouldn't know where to begin to write a shell script for this.

Comment: Likely achievable with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). We do have some Tasker veterans here - I'd wait for their move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs automation or using an app (if available) , i former is preferred option for me -[Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) is a versatile automation app:

You would need two macros

**Trigger :** *Power disconnected/ connected → connected*

**Actions:** : *Volume Change → set Ringer to your desired level as also others as you wish*

**Constraints:** None (Run always) or set up your Constraints under which macro runs

For the second macro, Trigger would be power disconnected and action would be Vibrate Enable

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help